# Unable to load asset flutter package

Tags: flutter

I can load image from assets/images directory in flutter application, but when load same image from assets directory in flutter package, i get this error:

Unable to load asset: assets/images/logo.png

Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/logo.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#d6b54(), name: "assets/images/logo.png", scale: 1.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When loading assets from a package, use the `package` parameter. Alternative, use the full path to the asset which would look something like `packages/<package_name>/assets/images/logo.png`.

```dart
final image = AssetImage(name: "assets/images/logo.png", package: 'package_name');
```

Also make sure your asset in your package is referenced in the `assets` in your package's `pubspec.yaml`.

```yaml
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Comment: Amazing, i wasted my time; thank you your solution worked.